# Batch Export PDF Properties

Tags: excel, pdf, adobe, batch-processing

**TL;DR**

I'm looking to take a file directory full of PDF files and "export" their properties, specifically the page number, to a .CSV file.

---

**Research**

I have found numerous programs that let me batch export the meta data of the PDF, but this typically has to do with the source information and not the information available about the PDF itself.

---

**Details**

I need the page numbers to be able to deduce the order of pages. I'm using for an indexing system that will allow two parties to locate and communicate about the documents. I plan to have an Excel document with the document titles and unique IDs that will need to correspond to sequential bates numbers on PDFs.

I don't mind coding or getting extensively creative with this, but it has to be something that can be done in batch as there are many many files.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: When you say "page numbers" do you mean the total number of pages in the PDF?

Comment: Yes. Since the bates numbers will be sequential, I'll be able to deduce the increase of bates numbers by the amount of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you don't mind coding, so here's a short Python script that does what you want (as I understand it).

```py
#!python3.6
import csv
import os

import fitz  # http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/


def main():
    """ Place script in same directory as PDFs. """
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    csv_filename = os.path.join(script_dir, 'pdf_information.csv')
    with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([
            'Filename',
            'Page Count',
        ])
        for basename in os.listdir(script_dir):
            if basename.upper().endswith('.PDF'):
                filename = os.path.join(script_dir, basename)
                pdf = fitz.open(filename)
                writer.writerow([
                    basename,
                    pdf.pageCount,
                ])
                pdf.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @jowens , while I have tested this, you're awesome! This looks brilliant. I have some experience with Python, but mainly syntax so I wouldn't even have thought to use it. I'll test it later. 

I apologize for my inexperience, but would I literally just run this in the Python console? (I ask because that sounds too straight forward and thus, miracle-esque.)

Comment: Install Python (I tested with version 3.6) and the PyMuPDF package (URL to documentation in code). Save the code as a *.py file and make sure your operating system knows how to run *.py files. Place the *.py file in the folder with your PDFs and run it and it should create a *.csv file.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you again. I'll test asap.

Comment: Alright, so I've been at this all night, while I have Python installed and going, I'm struggling with the basics of getting the PyMuPDF installed. When I enter the line suggested in the documentation (>>> pip install [--upgrade] PyMuPDF), I get a syntax error on "install." I"m going on vacation for the next few days, so I'll do some extensive reading on Python. If you know what might be causing that, you'd be a real life saver.

Comment: pip should be run from the operating system command line, not from within the Python shell.

Comment: Hey Owens, back from vacation. Spent a good chunk reading up on Python. I tried to run the " pip install [--upgrade] PyMuPDF" in Command Prompt and get a " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command.." I'll keep reading up to see what I can find, but the instructions on the PyMuPDF are a bit limited. If this is setting off any spidey senses, please just let me know. Thanks, sir.

Comment: Run it from C:\Python36\Scripts (assuming you installed Python there). You should be able to see pip.exe in the Scripts folder.

Comment: OK, figured out the issue, and got both pip working and installed the PyMuPDF via the command prompt. I placed the file in the directory, but when I try to run it, nothing happens. I loaded it into PyCharm to run it from there and got a ModuleNotFoundError. I'm going to go through my program files to see if I can confirm in the install of PyMuPDF, but just wanted to see if you had any thoughts?

Comment: Both a fitz folder and the PyMuPDF folder are located in the Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages directory.

Comment: Oh my. My only other thought is if you have multiple versions of Python installed your OS may be pointing to a different version than where you installed PyMuPDF (PyMuPDF can be installed in other versions). Also, check the version of Python PyCharm is using.

Comment: You mentioned making sure that my PC could run .py files. Besides having Python installed and the right PATH set up, is there anything else that would make it so that script wouldn't run? Even when I execute (via double click) on the file in the directory, it kind of pops something up real fast and then nada.

Comment: Alright, Owens. I got it to work through PyCharm. It just didn't have the base interpreter, and was trying to use PyCharms Project one, which didn't have PyMuPDF. You're my hero. Can't give you enough thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to reach out, but in using the code on a big batch, I got a RunTimeError: Cannot tell in file error: warning: cannot recognize version marker warning: repairing PDF document error: cannot tell in file.

I'm looking into how to fix this, but it did seem to cut the program short. Any thoughts to save me some digging?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt PDF. Note the PDF with the problem and see if it opens in Adobe Reader. You might have to set it aside.

Comment: Sure was. There was about 30 of them. Is there a way to set the code to ignore PDFs with a 0 file size?

Comment: Ah, thank you! I did a lot of studying and research about Python, but dang, there is a lot to know, haha.